# How to print the info, message, status, tags part which present in the log file on to the console in robotframework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

Can we print the marked in the console? Please click on the logfile for the image reference which is the log file of the robotframework.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Log` keyword and pass in `console=yes`

For example
`Log    Hello, console!    console=yes`

This is detailed here:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log

As far as logging the other data, you can find those in the [Automatic Variables](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables)

For example
`Log    Hello, from ${TEST_NAME}    console=yes`

Comment: Thank you for the information in details. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I want to know if the Info details/description which is present in the log file, can this be printed to console?

Comment: I tried something like this Log    testing, from ${LOG LEVEL}    console=True. But the output on the console was <testing, from INFO>. where in the log gives <09:51:16.784  INFO  File 'test.txt' does not exist>. I want to print exactly this information in the 'info' in log to be printed in the console